# Difference between BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER and onBackpressureBuffer operator in rxjava 2

Tags: java, stream, rx-java, backpressure

I am new to the world of reactive programming and I am trying to create a simple backpressure aware message processing using rxjava 2.

Following is the workflow I am trying to achieve:

1. Flowable of a continues string stream.
2. Perform a time consuming operation and change the message to another string
3. Perform another time consuming operation.

Now I am using following code:

```
{
    Flowable.create(subscriber -> {
             some_stream.forEach(data -> {
                subscriber.onNext(data);
            });
        }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER).
    subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()). // Data emission will run io scheduler
    observeOn(Schedulers.computation()). // Map operation will run on computation scheduler
    map(val -> Time_Consuming_Task(val)). // Task returns another string
    observeOn(Schedulers.io()).  / Next consumer will run on computation scheduler
    subscribe(val -> Another_Time_Consuming_Task(val));
}
```

Now for small operations I don't see any back pressure related issues.

But for large streams I don't know how it will behave.

Now My questions are:-

1. What is the default buffer size in case of **BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER** and where does the data gets buffered ?
2. What if I want to create two backpressure buffers, each before every time consuming task, should I use **onBackpressureBuffer operator** ?
3. If the buffer gets full, I don't want to lose data, I want to wait or something in that case ?

Comment: 1. infinite, 3. because of 1 it will just run out of memory 2. it's not creating a buffer in place of call, it's making whole downstream backpressure aware

Comment: @Than, Thanks for answer. I still didn't get Where does the data get buffered when we use BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER. And also in case of onBackpressureBuffer operator, how can I maintain two different buffers for two different time consuming tasks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## To answer your questions:

#### 1. The default buffer size differs by platform. On the JVM it is 128 items per ring buffer, on Android it is 16 item (*[Source](https://eng.uber.com/rxjava-backpressure/)*)

This has been lowered from the previous 1024 (you can see the change being implemented in RxJava [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/pull/1836)). There is also a system property which you can use to adjust it yourself if needed:

```
System.setProperty("rx.ring-buffer.size", "8");
```

As they are called *ring buffers*, they are stored in-memory. You can read more about them [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer).

#### 2. & 3. If it gets full, it starts overriding itself. In that case, use onBackpressureBuffer

> A consequence of the circular buffer is that when it is full and a subsequent write is performed, then it starts overwriting the oldest data.

*Quote from the wiki article about [Circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer)*.

When you know your `rx.ring-buffer.size`, the best thing you can do is to use the following API given in RxJava 2:

```
onBackpressureBuffer(int capacity, // This is the given bound, not a setter for the ring buffer
    Action0 onOverflow, // The desired action to execute
    BackpressureOverflow.Strategy strategy) // The desired strategy to use
```

Again, as I could not say it any better, let me quote the RxJava wiki on [Backpressure (2.0)](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Backpressure-(2.0)#onbackpressurebufferint-capacity):

> The BackpressureOverflow.Strategy is an interface actually but the class BackpressureOverflow offers 4 static fields with implementations of it representing typical actions:
>
> - `ON_OVERFLOW_ERROR`: this is the default behavior of the previous two overloads, signalling a BufferOverflowException
> - `ON_OVERFLOW_DEFAULT`: currently it is the same as ON_OVERFLOW_ERROR
> - `ON_OVERFLOW_DROP_LATEST`: if an overflow would happen, the current value will be simply ignored and only the old values will be delivered once the downstream requests.
> - `ON_OVERFLOW_DROP_OLDEST`: drops the oldest element in the buffer and adds the current value to it.
>
> Note that the last two strategies cause discontinuity in the stream as they drop out elements. In addition, they won't signal BufferOverflowException.

Here's an example:

```
Flowable.range(1, 1_000_000)
          .onBackpressureBuffer(16, () -> { },
              BufferOverflowStrategy.ON_OVERFLOW_DROP_OLDEST)
          .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
          .subscribe(e -> { }, Throwable::printStackTrace);
```

---

Worthy of noting:

> The `Observable` type in RxJava 2.x has no concept of backpressure. Implementing `Observable` is effectively the same as using `onBackpressureBuffer()` by default. UI events, one-off network requests, and state changes should all work with this approach. The `Completable`, `Maybe`, and `Single` types can also dictate this behavior.
>
> If you need to support backpressure, RxJava 2.x’s new class, `Flowable`, is backpressure-aware like `Observable` was in RxJava 1.x. However, the updated library now requires an explicit choice of a backpressure strategy to prevent surprise `MissingBackpressureExceptions`.

Read more:

- [src/main/java/rx/internal/util/RxRingBuffer.java#L246](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/1.x/src/main/java/rx/internal/util/RxRingBuffer.java#L246)